# Delete a json key-vaue in nunjucks variable

Tags: node.js, nunjucks, gulp-nunjucks-render

I am stuck at a point where I want to delete a key-value pair from json object in nunjucks template variable.

I have an object: `var json = {"id": "123", "obj": {"id": "456", "name": "testing"}, "name":"test", "template": "{% set object = json.obj %}{{object}}"}`

In this I am getting entire object without modification.
So how can I achieve this in nunjucks template variable?

Comment: What do you want to delete? oh the `name`?

Comment: @Michelem I tried your solution but still not able to get expected value, I update the object as per my requirement. Is there way to either delete or add any key into json object within nunjucks template variable?

Comment: What exactly do you want to delete? Be more specific

Comment: Do you want to delete something before or after rendering?

Comment: @DushyantBangal I want to delete before rendering.

Comment: for any json variable, you can just use `delete myObject.keyName` and it will be deleted.
You could just do that before rendering.

Comment: @DushyantBangal I want to delete during assign it like `"template": "{% set object = json.obj %}{{delete object.name}}{{object}}` and then print the entire object and expected `name` key will not be appear because it should deleted, but its not working as I am expecting and exist `name` key still

Comment: Let me get at this from a different angle. Nunjucks does not exist in a vacuum. Depending what are you using to compile the templates, you should "massage" the data there. For example, Gulp has amazing `gulp-data` which you can load your environment variables (and modify them too). Same should apply for Jinja environments on Python for example. I think you are approaching this at a wrong place. Data should be fed into Nunjucks already prepared, you should just do actions upon it, not radically change the data like deletion etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set it as null or undefined:

```
{% set obj.name = null %}
```

Comment: I am unable to set a key to null or undefined from an object.